# Run MongoDB query to update a sequence field in a loop

Tags: mongodb, shell, nosql

I have a collection that I admittedly screwed up with an export from 1 db and import into another.

I have a field on the collection called 'seqNo' that simply keeps a running count of the documents, and during the import I imported duplicate seqNo values.

I'm trying now, to figure out how to iterate through the documents in the collection, update the documents after 1, with an incrementing counter for that seqNo.

I've been reading the docs, and see how to insert with an incrementing number, but seems more like a function, and not sure how to do this with an update.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Is where I'm looking, and seems more like a permanent thing, and not really what I'm looking to do.

Comment: This is a one-time fix, yes?  You just want to iterate over the entire collection, sorted in a way that is meaningful to you, and increment and update seqNo as you go?

Comment: yes, and I figured it out as well.  Used `forEach()` in mongo shell, then a short function to iterate through a counter, and update each one as I went. I'll add my solution above in my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer using this.

In mongo shell first set an initial value for a counter.

`var counter = 0`

You can check this counter anytime in mongo shell by just typing in the variable name and pressing return.

`> counter`

`0`

Now, create a `forEach` function and iterate the counter as you go.

```
db.questions.find({}).forEach(function(doc){ 
  var = counter + 1; 
  db.questions.update({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { seqNo: counter }}); 
})
```

It took me a few tries to realize I do need the qualifier on the update portion of `_id: doc._id`.  Without that, it did not update anything.

Comment: I think you meant    var seq = 0

Comment: I sure did, and I corrected the whole thing to use the same var all the way through.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Still need fixing. `var = counter + 1` should be `counter = counter + 1`